# Como pode ser traduzido "elevator pitch"?

Tags: tradução, tradução-inglês

Na página do [beta privado](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/whats-beta) dos sites da SE, existe uma pergunta "que deve ser respondida para o trabalho de crescimento da comunidade":

> *What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?*

O que exatamente é *elevator pitch* e como pode ser traduzido para o português (pt-br de preferência).

Comment: elevator speech e elevator pitch são sinônimos?

Comment: @Peixoto estás-lhe a perguntar? Se ele não sabe o que é um elevator pitch, não vai saber se é sinónimo de outra coisa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A wikipedia traz como sinônimo elevator speech e elevator pitch:

> Elevator pitch, elevator speech or elevator statement is a short sales
>   pitch; that is, a summary used to quickly and simply define a process,
>   product, service, organization, or event and its value proposition.

Fonte: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elevator_pitch)

O forum englishexperts traduz para Abordagem de Elevador.

> Elevator pitch( Abordagem de vendas no elevador) é um pequeno
>   pré-preparado que explica sobre uma empresa, um produto, um serviço,
>   uma pessoa, um evento, uma organização etc.de forma clara e suscinta.
>   O elevador representa o tempo que você tem para fazer a abordagem (1
>   minuto, a média que você fica dentro do elevador). Portanto, trata-se
>   da abordagem de vendas que você consegue fazer de seu negócio em 1
>   minuto. Normalmente isto não se aplica a produtos e serviços para um
>   cliente, e sim à venda de uma idéia ou negócio para outro interessado
>   (por exemplo, um investidor).

Fonte: [EnglishExperts](https://www.englishexperts.com.br/forum/traducao-de-elevator-pitch-t35409.html)

Dessa forma, traduziria como: **Abordagem de vendas no Elevador**, **Discurso de Elevador** ou **Abordagem de Elevador**,

Comment: Discurso de Elevador acho que é o que mais se aplica